# How to fetch the data of evolution chain from the PokeApi

Tags: flutter, dart

The JSON object that is being returned when requested for the evolution data is kind of complex for me to work with. So can someone help me with how can I fetch the data in a manner such that the representation of the data will be easier later on? I need this data for my flutter app. Here is the JSON URL for the data:
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/67/

Comment: https://www.webinovers.com/web-tools/json-to-dart-convertor, 
use this service to automatically create JSON to Dart model calss

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Fetch the pokemon-species: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/ivysaur
**2.** look at .evolution_chain -> https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/1/
**3.** Fetch the chain: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/1/
**4.** Parse the JSON and get the full list of evolutions.
You can find the original answer [here](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokeapi/issues/661)